# File can't be accessed on Linux cluster

Tags: linux, chmod, hpc, lsf

I am trying to run a job on a Linux cluster.

I am trying to read a file `/storage1/fs1/Active/LP6005120-DNA_B02.bam`.

I did `chmod 755 /storage1/fs1/Active/LP6005120-DNA_B02.bam` before submitting the job that tries to access this file. It ran for the first time, but when I try to submit the same job again, I am  getting error saying `ERROR, cannot read /storage1/fs1/Active/LP6005120-DNA_B02.bam`. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Check if `noexec` flag is set

Comment: @dejdej This is what I have for `ls -lht`: `-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mpps domain users 131G Nov 25 21:06 /storage1/fs1/Active/LP6005120-DNA_B02.bam`

Comment: Try `mount | grep storage1` and see if you can find it the flag noexec e.g: `(ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)` or  check  the filesystem and mountpoint first with  `df -h` and then grep it

Comment: @dejdej `mount | grep storage` shows : `cache1-fs1 on /storage1/fs1 type gpfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)`

Comment: ok so that is not the issue, you can take a look at which processes are using your file: `fuser  LP6005120-DNA_B02.bam` or `lsof  LP6005120-DNA_B02.bam` .